# Stream multiple filter internals

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to understand internal calls of Stream API of Java.

I have the following code, which has two filter (intermediate) operations and one terminal operation.

```
IntStream.of(1,2,3)
    .filter(e->e%2==0)
    .filter(e->e==2)
    .forEach(e->System.out.println(e));
```

Stream - > returns Stream with overridden filter - > returns Stream with overridden filter - > terminal

I see that for each intermediate operation a new stream is returned with overridden `filter` method. Once it hits the terminal method, the stream executes the `filter`. I see that `filter()` is being run twice if there are two `filter`  operations instead of once.

I want to understand how one stream traversal is able to call filter twice.

Pasting the IntPipeline code below which is hit for the  filter method in Stream.

```
@Override
public final IntStream filter(IntPredicate predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    return new StatelessOp<Integer>(this, StreamShape.INT_VALUE,
                                    StreamOpFlag.NOT_SIZED) {
        @Override
        Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<Integer> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedInt<Integer>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void begin(long size) {
                    downstream.begin(-1);
                }

                @Override
                public void accept(int t) {
                    if (predicate.test(t)) ///line 11
                        downstream.accept(t);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

The `filter()` returns a new Stream whose predicate is set as `e%2==0` and then again a new Stream is returned whose predicate is `e==2`. Once the terminal operation is hit the, for each traversal the predicates code is executed then at line 11.

Edit :  I see that `downstream` is used to link the intermediate ops as a LinkedList. So all the implementations are added to the `linkedlist` as previous stage and called once traversal starts?

Comment: I dont really follow the question. You have setup an operation pipeline consisting of two filters, like two `if` statements, and the sum collector. So when it executes, the pipeline is executed on each element one by one. Executing two filters (like `if` statements) on each element and then adding it to the sum collector.

Comment: When I see the implementation of Stream, for intermediate operation, like filter, filter is overridden and new stream is returned. Then if another filter is chained, filter  method is overridden again. I want to understand how same is able to overide filter method twice . Also how is it able to hit it twice?

Comment: What do you mean by _overridden_? There is nothing overridden here. The `filter` method is just called.

Comment: Additionally, this code does not compile and thus cannot be talked about in a good way.

Comment: eidted my code. When i looked at source code of Stream, for each intermediate operation, the function(filter here) is getting added and a new Stream returns.  And finally the terminal operation hits, all the intermediate operations are executed. So I thought the stream's methods are overridden for all intermediate opertaions

Comment: Instead of _talking_ about the source code, show it and explain it based on that. Otherwise the question is just unclear since your interpretations of the source seem to be incorrect.

Comment: added the source code I was referring to . Thanks

Comment: When you say you want “to understand how one stream traversal is able to call filter twice”, what is your reason to assume that the filter method can not be called twice, or as many times as someone wishes, like any other method?

Comment: @Holger : I thought a Stream can have only one filter method, but looks like there is a pipeline where all the intermediates are chained as form of LinkedList. During traversal pipleine methods are execute in the order as in the list.

Comment: The linked list is an implementation detail. There are many ways to implement such an API. See, e.g. `BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ONE.add(BigInteger.ONE).add( BigInteger.TEN .multiply(BigInteger.TWO).multiply(BigInteger.TWO));` works fundamentally different. Still, invoking the same method more than once is no problem. Likewise, you can easily maintain multiple predicates in a single variable, e.g. `IntPredicate p = e -> e%2==0; p = p.and(e -> e==2);`

Comment: OK, So LinkedList is not important here but the idea of chaining, thanks

Comment: @Holger Perhaps you could sum up your comments in an answer. Specifically, this idea of chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to do my best to explain what is happening behind the scene in Stream API, First of all you should change your mind about how you have been programming so far, try to get this new idea.

So to have an example of real world imagine factory( I mean real factory in real world not factory design pattern), in a factory we have some raw material and some consecutive processes in different stages that turn the raw material into finished product. to have a grasp of this concept see the following diagram:

(stage1)raw material -> (stage2) process the input and pass the output to the next stage -> (stage3) process the input and pass the output to the next stage -> .....

So the  output of the first stage is the raw material and all subsequent stages do some processing on their input and pass it along(for example it can turn the input of the stage to something else or rejects that input completely because of its low quality) then after it will hand over the output to another stage which is in front of it. from now on we call this consecutive stages altogether a Pipeline.

> what is processing?, it can be anything, for instance one stage can decide to turn the input to completely different thing and pass it along( this is exactly what `map` provides us with in Stream API), another stage may allow  input to pass along based on some condition(this is exactly what `filter` does in Stream API).

Java Stream API does something similar to a factory. Each Stream is exactly a pipeline and you can add another stage to each pipeline and create a new pipeline, so when you write `IntStream.of(1,2,3)` you have created a pipeline which is `IntStream` so let's break down your code:

```
IntStream intStream = IntStream.of(1,2,3)
```

This is the equivalent to raw material in our factory, therefore it is a pipeline which has only one stage. However having a pipeline which only passes the raw material has no benefit. Let's add another stage to the previous pipeline and create a new Pipeline:

```
IntStream evenNumbePipeline = intStream.filter(e -> e%2==0);
```

Please note that here you create new Pipeline and this pipeline is exactly the previous one plus another stage that allow only even number pass through and rejects other ones. When you call filter method following portion of the code create exactly a new Pipeline:

```
@Override
public final IntStream filter(IntPredicate predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    return new StatelessOp<Integer>(this, StreamShape.INT_VALUE,
                                    StreamOpFlag.NOT_SIZED) {
        @Override
        Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<Integer> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedInt<Integer>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void begin(long size) {
                    downstream.begin(-1);
                }

                @Override
                public void accept(int t) {
                    if (predicate.test(t)) ///line 11
                        downstream.accept(t);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

You can see filter return new instance of `StatelessOp<Integer>` which extends IntPipeline as below:

```
abstract static class StatelessOp<E_IN> extends IntPipeline<E_IN>
```

Let's stop here for a moment with a question: Has any operation done so far? The answer is a BIG NO, when you create a factory or pipeline of the factory no product has been produced yet, You should provide the raw material to the pipeline to get your finished product by factory, but we haven't done it so far. so when we are calling filter and other operation in stream we are just designing our pipeline procedures and we don't really process anything, we are just adding another stage to our pipeline and say hey when you are given the input you should do this procedure on it,

In our case we add stage2 to our factory and tell it when you are given the input check if it is even or not and then after allow it to pass along if it is an even number. We are reaching to your question now let's add another stage to our pipeline:

```
IntStream onlyTwo = evenNumbePipeline.filter(e -> e==2);
```

Here you create new pipeline which get the previous pipeline (which is `evenNumbePipeline`) and add another stage to that pipeline(evenNumbePipeline has not changed, we create new pipeline which has evenNumbePipeline inside it). Let's take a look at our pipeline so far:

```
raw material(stage1) -> filter even number(stage2) -> filter only 2(stage3)
```

Think about it as the definition of the stages in our pipeline and not operation, maybe we don't have raw material yet but we can design our factory so that we can provide it with raw material later. You can see this pipeline has three stages and each stage does something to the previous stage output. Pipeline will be provided by raw material one by one(forget about parallel stream fro now) so when you provide 1 as raw material to this pipeline it goes through these stages. Each of this stage is new Object in java.

So lets get to something you said in your question

> I want to understand how one stream traversal is able to call filter
> twice.

From what we have investigated so far do you think traversal of the Stream has called filter method twice or when we created our pipeline we have called filter method twice?

We call this `filter` method twice because we want to have two different stages in our pipeline. Think about a factory we call filter method twice because we want to have two different filter stages in our factory when we are designing it. We have not traversed the factory stages yet and we have not produced any finished product yet.

Let's have some fun and produce some output:

```
onlyTwo.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

As `foreach` is a terminal operation, it starts our factory and provides raw material to our factory's pipeline. So for instance 1 go through stage2 then stage3 and then delivered to `foreach` statement.

But there is another question: how can we define what each stage does when we are designing our pipeline?

In our example when we were designing our pipeline we called filter method to create new stage and pass to it something that filter stage should do as a parameter the name of this parameter is predicate. The operation that exactly executed when input received(by each stage) is define by `opWrapSink` method in each stage. Therefore we have to implement this method when we are creating our stage so let's get back to our filter method where Stream classs create new Stage for us:

```
@Override
public final IntStream filter(IntPredicate predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    return new StatelessOp<Integer>(this, StreamShape.INT_VALUE,
                                    StreamOpFlag.NOT_SIZED) {
        @Override
        Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<Integer> sink) {
            return new Sink.ChainedInt<Integer>(sink) {
                @Override
                public void begin(long size) {
                    downstream.begin(-1);
                }

                @Override
                public void accept(int t) {
                    if (predicate.test(t)) ///line 11
                        downstream.accept(t);
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

You can see each stage's `opWrapSink` methods return a `Sink` but what's the `Sink`?

To put away lots of complexity in this interface it is a consumer and has an accept method as below(it has also has many other accept method for primitive types to avoid unnecessary boxing and unboxing) :

```
void accept(T t);
```

When you are implementing this interface you should define what you want to do with the input value that you will be delivered as input in the stage. You don't need to implement this interface in your program because methods in `Stream` implementations have done the heavy lifting for you. Let's see how it has been implemented in filter case:

```
@Override
Sink<Integer> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<Integer> sink) {
    return new Sink.ChainedInt<Integer>(sink) {
        @Override
        public void begin(long size) {
            downstream.begin(-1);
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(int t) {
            if (predicate.test(t)) ///line 11
                downstream.accept(t);
        }
    };
}
```

Stream framework  provides `opWrapSink` method with the next stage `Sink`(as the second parameter when calling this method), it means we know how the next stage in our Pipeline do their job(with the help of this `Sink`) but we should provide them with an input, it is crystal clear that the input to the next stage is the output of the current stage. another parameter that we need to produce the output of the current stage is the input to our current stage.

> input to our current stage -> do operation of the current stage on the
> input -> pass the output to the next stages(following stages in the
> pipeline)

So in the `accept` method we have input to our current stage as parameter `t` we should do something on this input(as the operation of our current stage on the input) and then pass it to the next stage. In our filter stage we need to check if the input to our stage which is `t` passes a `predicate`(which in our case is e%2==0) and then after we should pass it to the next stage `Sink`. And here is exactly what our accept method do(downstream is exactly the `Sink` for the following stages in the pipeline):

```
@Override
public void accept(int t) {
    if (predicate.test(t)) ///line 11
        downstream.accept(t);
}
```

What you should notice in this `accept` method implementation is that it only passes the input of the current stage(which is t) to the next stages if it passes a predicate(which in our case is e%2==0) and if it does not passes the predicate it does not pass it through(It is exactly what we expect from the filtering stage to do);

Answer (score 6):

I think you are having some burden and mixed concepts in your understanding of Streams.

1. Your confusion has nothing to do with *filter* (or any other operation) implementation; nor does there exist a concept of overriding an intermediate (or any other) stream operation;

   <sup>[Overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) is a completely different concept and it is related to *Inheritance*</sup>
2. Every single stream is a *single pipeline*, which has a (1) *beginning*, (2) optionally an *intermediate part*, and (3) the *end/conclusion*;
3. Intermediate operations are not overridden; they, instead, form a sequential chain of operations, which every element of the stream will have to go through (unless an element is discarded at some intermediate operation), in the order of same sequence.

   > *<sup>Think of Stream of K objects, as a pipe, in which instances of K will go through. That pipe has a beginning/source (where objects are entering the pipe), and the end/destination; however, in between, there might be several intermediate operations which will (either) filter, transform, box, or etc. those objects. Streams are *lazy*, meaning, that intermediate operations are not performed until the terminal operation is invoked (this is a [great feature of streams](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-streams-api-laziness)), so, each item, one at a time, will go through this pipe, when the terminal operation is invoked.</sup>*

Additionally, read [this snippet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> To perform a computation, stream operations are composed into a stream pipeline. A stream pipeline consists of a source (which might be an array, a collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero or more intermediate operations (which transform a stream into another stream, such as *`filter(Predicate)`*), and a terminal operation (which produces a result or side-effect, such as *`count()`* or *`forEach(Consumer)`*). Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed.

Remember the paradigm, that Stream consists of:

1. *Sourcer operation* - one that obtains stream from some set of some objects, or represents an existing stream object (*transactions* on the picture below);
2. *Intermediate operation**s*** - that could be 0 or more, and that are needed to introduce intermediary fine-graining, adjusting or modifying operations on your stream (*filter*, *sorted*, and *map* on the picture below);
3. *Terminal operation* - that terminates and closes stream. It can *produce* (return) something, *consume* (accept) something, neither, or both (*collect* on the picture below).

[image]

If you are still confused (which should not be the case now), you can additionally refer to [few important points](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) that may shed some more light on your confusions:

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed;

> Processing streams lazily allows for significant efficiencies; in a pipeline such as the filter-map-sum example above, filtering, mapping, and summing can be fused into a single pass on the data, with minimal intermediate state. Laziness also allows avoiding examining all the data when it is not necessary; for operations such as "find the first string longer than 1000 characters", it is only necessary to examine just enough strings to find one that has the desired characteristics without examining all of the strings available from the source. (This behavior becomes even more important when the input stream is infinite and not merely large.)

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` method is not overridden, but it is called with different lambda expressions.

If you "explode" the lambda expressions to anonymous classes, you will get something like this:

```
IntStream.of(1,2,3)
        .filter(new IntPredicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(int e) {
                return e % 2 == 0;
            }
        })
        .filter(new IntPredicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(int e) {
                return e == 2;
            }
        })
        .forEach(new IntConsumer() {
            @Override
            public void accept(int e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });
```

You see that `InStream.of(int...)` is a kind of factory method, that creates an implementation of an IntStream with the given values.
Since the `filter` method gives back an IntStream again, you can do chaining and call `filter` of that instance again. It is defined that you get a new instance here everytime ("Intermediate operations return a new stream.").

The implementation can be the same, so `filter` does not have to be overridden.

In fact, in the Java 8 version currently installed here on my machine (OpenJDK 1.8.0_181), decompiling the implementations show that `java.util.stream.IntStream.of(int...)` delegates to `java.util.Arrays.stream(int[])` and that returns actually an instance of `java.util.stream.IntPipeline.Head`. `IntPipeline` extends `java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline`, `AbstractPipeline` extends `java.util.stream.PipelineHelper` and that extends nothing (but `Object`, I wouldn't count that ;-) )

So `java.util.LinkedList` is not extended or modified for the filtering part, maybe it comes into play in the `foreach` method, but I didn't investigate that far as I thought you were more interested to the filtering.

I used IntelliJ IDEA to automatically replace the lambda expressions with anonymous classes and also do the decompiling stuff of the Java implementations - if you are interested in more details of the Java implementation you might give it a look (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/, the free community edition is by far sufficient for that kind of research)

Comment: Thanks....I understood partly by debugging in eclipse. But not very clear